# Preselected options in UIPickerView when app starts SWIFT

Tags: swift, xcode, label, uipickerview

I am new at Swift and I need help.
I have 4 UIPickerViews that have some data. Result ( that are combination of 4 ) is shown in Label. And everything is working smoothly, but what I want is, when the app starts there is some preselected values in those pickerviews that are not showing results before I manually change those values. When I start picking values I get results in Label. My question is how to show those results when the app starts with those preselected values?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: show a minimal example code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

This should probably do the trick:

```swift
yourPicker.selectRow(<index of item you want to select>, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```

Also if the labels are not showing the correct text, then you can also do:

```swift
myLabel.text = yourPickerData[<index of item you want to select>]
```

Comment: Sorry, I probably said it wrong. There is only one result depending on combination of values that user chose from those pickerviews. And there are default values, preselected to say. I get the result when I start chosing values but I want the result to be shown as soon as the app starts.